# How can I store an org-link to a list of search results from ivy-occur?

Tags: org-mode, ivy, counsel

When I use `counsel-rg` to grep through a directory hierarchy, once a list of search results has been displayed in the minibuffer, I can use `ivy-occur` to save the list in a dedicated buffer.

How can I instruct org-mode so that `org-store-link` can preserve a permanent link to such a buffer and `org-insert-link` can insert one and hitting `org-return` when the cursor is over such a link will re-run the search command and bring up a corresponding `ivy-occur` buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dedicated buffers you are talking about in your question are `ivy-occur-grep-mode`-buffers.
Those are filled by `counsel-ag-occur`.
Only the default directory and the buffer name containing the search words are needed for `counsel-ag-occur`.
That information must be present in the links to `ivy-occur-grep-mode`-buffers.
The following lisp code defines a new org link type `councelrg` with the corresponding functions for following and storing the link.

Links of that type consist of a elisp cons with the `default-directory` in the `car` and the buffer name in the `cdr`.
Those links are read by `read` in `org+-counselrg-follow`.

```el
(defconst org+-counselrg-link-type "counselrg"
  "String for identifying counsel-rg links.")

(defun org+-buffer-base-name (buffer-name)
  "Remove trailing <.*> in BUFFER-NAME."
  (save-match-data
    (when (string-match "<[^<>]+>\\'" buffer-name)
      (setq buffer-name (substring buffer-name nil (match-beginning 0)))))
  buffer-name)

(defun org+-counselrg-store ()
  "Store links of type counselrg:LINK-PATH."
  (when (derived-mode-p 'ivy-occur-grep-mode)
    (org-store-link-props :type org+-counselrg-link-type
              :link (format "%s:%S" org+-counselrg-link-type (cons default-directory (org+-buffer-base-name (buffer-name))))
              :description (format "%s in %s" (buffer-name) default-directory))
    t))

(defun org+-counselrg-follow (link-path)
  "Follow org-links of type counselrg:LINK-PATH."
  (let* ((caller-window (get-buffer-window))
     (dir-buf (read link-path))
     (dir-name (car dir-buf))
     (buf-name (cdr dir-buf))
     (buf
      ;; First try to re-use already existing buffer.
      (cl-loop for buf in (buffer-list)
           if (with-current-buffer buf
            (and
             (derived-mode-p 'ivy-occur-grep-mode)
             (file-equal-p default-directory dir-name)
             (string-equal
              (org+-buffer-base-name (buffer-name))
              buf-name
              )))
           do (with-current-buffer buf (ivy-occur-revert-buffer))
           and return buf
           finally
           ;; if there is no buffer for re-use:
           return
           (with-current-buffer (generate-new-buffer buf-name)
             (setq default-directory dir-name)
             (ivy-occur-grep-mode)
             (let ((inhibit-read-only t)
               (counsel-ag-base-command counsel-rg-base-command))
               (setq-local ivy-occur-last
                   (make-ivy-state
                    :directory default-directory
                    :caller 'counsel-ag
                    :window caller-window
                    :buffer (current-buffer)
                    ))
               (counsel-ag-occur))
             (current-buffer))
           )))
    (switch-to-buffer buf)))

(org-link-set-parameters org+-counselrg-link-type
             :follow #'org+-counselrg-follow
             :store #'org+-counselrg-store)
```

If you like to try the code put it into your `*scratch*` buffer and evaluate the buffer with `eval-buffer`.
If you even want to install the code put it into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) and restart emacs.

Comment: I am loving this! thanks!

Comment: had to change (counsel-ag-occur) to (counsel-rg-occur)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `counsel` or `ivy`, but you can execute arbitrary elisp as part of a link.  If I wanted to store search results from, say, `M-x occur`, I would use something like: `[[elisp:(occur "phrase")][Search for phrase in this buffer]]`

That approach has the downside of prompting you to `Execute ... as elisp (y or n)`, which could be annoying.  If you make this sort of link often, you might consider adding a custom link type with `(org-add-link-type "occur" (lambda (key) (occur key)))` And then you can type `occur:blah`, and it will be highlighted as a link without a prompt.  You'll have to change it to work with `ivy-occur` of course.